# structuring cross-platform apps (electron + mobile + web)

Tags: angular, architecture, electron, cross-platform

While developing an app for mobile, desktop and web, and use electron to target desktop, for mobile i would ionic or nativescript, and the web would be basically the same as electron but with less functionality.
How should i structure my project?

```
- node_modules
- projects
  - electron build
  - mobile build
  - web build
  - angular common   
- test
- doc
```

most of the core app ui/functionalities would live inside angular common, each build would basically be responsible for selecting which things to use, and how to make the platform specific functions work like storage / electron using sqlite, and web not storing locally & etc..

I would also appreciate any suggestion of platforms/frameworks to build to those targets (mobile / web / desktop)

Something like this would work? there is any best-practices or performance guidelines i could study/refer to when making decisions?